# Header files setup when using c++ class in multiple source/header files

Tags: c++, class, header

Currently I have a large class `Policy` that is declared and defined, respectively, in files named `globals.h` and `globals.cpp`.  In addition to the `Policy` class, these files hold several other classes and functions that use the `Policy` class.  Because of compilation time issues, I now want to separate the `Policy` class from everything else.  I want all the other classes and all the functions that use `Policy` to be defined in another source file, so that when I change the `Policy` class, I don't have to recompile all the other classes and functions.

However, when I tried to separate things, I got lots of "field has incomplete type" errors when trying to use the `Policy` class.  I believe they were due to incorrect use of `#include` statements.

Below I have tried to mimic my setup in a simple and concise manner.  Note that there are many other source files that also `#include "globals.h"`.

**globals.h:**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H_
#define GLOBALS_H_

class Policy;

class A {
    A(std::vector<Policy>);
};

class Policy {

    // many member objects and functions declared
};

void func1(Policy&);
void func2(Policy&);

#endif
```

**globals.cpp:**

```
#include "globals.h"

A::A(std:vector<Policy> p) {
    // do stuff
}

//
// Define all of Policy's member functions
//

void func1(Policy& p) {
    // do stuff
}

void func2(Policy& p) {
    // do stuff
}
```

So, now I will get to my specific (though open-ended and possibly vague) question...

**QUESTION:** Given that I originally had the setup described above, and given that when I tried to split the content above into `policy.cpp` and `policy.h`, and `other.cpp` and `other.h`, I  encountered lots of "field has incomplete type" errors, what kind of mistakes did I probably make?

---

My hope is that responses to this question will help me to identify issues that I can carefully study before I attempt again to split up my code.
After making the changes and encountering the errors, I gave up and reverted to the original setup described above.  Later, however, I decided to rethink and retry splitting the content into multiple source files.  So, I don't have specific problem code that I can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include `<vector>` before including other headers that contain `std::vector<Something>`. For instance, in `globals.cpp` add `#include <vector>` before `#include "globals.h"`.

Also, you can't use a forward-declared struct/class type like `Policy` from `globals.h` in types that require to know its size (like `std::vector<Policy>`). `std::vector<*Policy>` would work though.